# Mouse on control immediately lost

Tags: wpf

my intention is to capture the mouse events for a specific control, but the mouse capture is instantly lost

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TryMouseCapture.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="lbl" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" GotMouseCapture="lbl_GotMouseCapture" IsEnabled="True" LostMouseCapture="lbl_LostMouseCapture" MouseLeftButtonDown="lbl_MouseLeftButtonDown">Mouse captured here</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">Click here</Label>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Click="Button_Click">Capture Mouse in the first label</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

code behind

```
    private void lbl_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = (Label)sender;
        var b = label.IsMouseCaptured;
    }

    private void lbl_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var b = Mouse.Capture(lbl);            
    }

    private void lbl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

So after clicking the button, the `lbl_GotMouseCapture`is called, and then immediately `lbl_LostMouseCapture` follows.

Is there something else to do, besides calling `Mouse.Capture(lbl);` ?

Comment: My guess is that's because on button_click, you have a breakpoint. When hit, the VS debugger pops up and that makes you lose the capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the code works. But setting the b variable implies that you are setting breakpoints. I would replace those by Debug statements to start with..

Answer (score 1):

You should set also

`e.Handled = true;`

in your `Button_Click` event handling to make it working everywhere.